# How to display an svg image in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, svg, axios, react-bootstrap

I am working on a web application with Nodejs and Reactjs and currently i'm retrieving data from the mongo database and displaying it with react.

Here is some code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from '../../node_modules/axios';
import {Col,Card} from 'react-bootstrap';

import {BrowserRouter as Router,Link, useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';

const Brand = props => (
<Col lg="4" className="d-inline-block">
  <Link to="/admin/Marques/MarqueDetails/1">
  <Card className="marque-card" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <p>{props.brand.name}</p>
      <Card.Img className="marque-card" variant="top" src={`../../public/` + 
       props.brand.imgUrl} />
  </Card>
  </Link>
</Col>
)

class cardBrand extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {brands: []};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/brand/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ brands: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
  brandList() {
    return this.state.brands.map(currentBrand => {
      return <Brand brand={currentBrand} key={currentBrand._id}/>;
    })
  }
render() {
    return(
      <Col lg="12">
       { this.brandList() }
       </Col>
    )
  }
}
export default cardBrand;
```

As you can see i have the `img/brand` folders inside the `public` folder and the `props.brand.imgUrl` contains the path and the image name, but unfortunately it's not working on the browser, here is an image :

P.S : i already tried `react-svg` but nothing happened, maybe because i didn't know how to use it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: the issue is not for svg. the issue is for path. provide the right path where you have store the svg file

Comment: i knew it ! would you please tell me how should i do it ? thanks !

Comment: is the svg files are store at another server?

Comment: currently not, but it will be, but right now i stored my images in the public folder (manually added)

Comment: provided path with base_url like (http://localhost:3000/public/....)

Comment: can you show me file structure??

Comment: use ```src={`/${props.brand.imgUrl}`}```

Comment: unrelated to solving the problem, but related to the code you're writing: if you're using template strings, don't use string concatenation. The whole reason template strings exist is to do away with that: Instead of `'../../public/' + props.brand.imgUrl` (using single quotes as backticks because of backticks being active in comments), write `'../../public/${props.brand.imgUrl}'` (again, using single quotes here, but those should be back ticks).

Comment: change ```import axios from '../../node_modules/axios';``` to ```import axios from 'axios';```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, looks like your svg path is `img/brand/svg-name.svg`. to display the image don't include public in your source. for example, to display images in `public/img/brand` you use

```
// without specifying public directory
<img alt="test" src={'/img/brand/svg-name.svg'}/>
```

Change your card src to

```
<Card.Img className="marque-card" variant="top" src={`/${props.brand.imgUrl}`} />
```